# Keep only duplicates from a DataFrame regarding some field

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this spark DataFrame:

```python
+---+-----+------+----+------------+------------+
| ID|  ID2|Number|Name|Opening_Hour|Closing_Hour|
+---+-----+------+----+------------+------------+
|ALT|  QWA|     6|null|    08:59:00|    23:30:00|
|ALT|AUTRE|     2|null|    08:58:00|    23:29:00|
|TDR|  QWA|     3|null|    08:57:00|    23:28:00|
|ALT| TEST|     4|null|    08:56:00|    23:27:00|
|ALT|  QWA|     6|null|    08:55:00|    23:26:00|
|ALT|  QWA|     2|null|    08:54:00|    23:25:00|
|ALT|  QWA|     2|null|    08:53:00|    23:24:00|
+---+-----+------+----+------------+------------+
```

I want to get a new dataframe with only the lines that are not unique regarding the 3 fields `"ID"`, `"ID2"` and `"Number"`.

It means that I want this DataFrame:

```python
+---+-----+------+----+------------+------------+
| ID|  ID2|Number|Name|Opening_Hour|Closing_Hour|
+---+-----+------+----+------------+------------+
|ALT|  QWA|     6|null|    08:59:00|    23:30:00|
|ALT|  QWA|     2|null|    08:53:00|    23:24:00|
+---+-----+------+----+------------+------------+
```

Or maybe a dataframe with all the duplicates:

```python
+---+-----+------+----+------------+------------+
| ID|  ID2|Number|Name|Opening_Hour|Closing_Hour|
+---+-----+------+----+------------+------------+
|ALT|  QWA|     6|null|    08:59:00|    23:30:00|
|ALT|  QWA|     6|null|    08:55:00|    23:26:00|
|ALT|  QWA|     2|null|    08:54:00|    23:25:00|
|ALT|  QWA|     2|null|    08:53:00|    23:24:00|
+---+-----+------+----+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One way to do this is by using a [`pyspark.sql.Window`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) to add a column that counts the number of duplicates for each row's `("ID", "ID2", "Number")` combination. Then select only the rows where the number of duplicate is greater than 1.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('ID', 'ID2', 'Number')
df.select('*', f.count('ID').over(w).alias('dupeCount'))\
    .where('dupeCount > 1')\
    .drop('dupeCount')\
    .show()
#+---+---+------+----+------------+------------+
#| ID|ID2|Number|Name|Opening_Hour|Closing_Hour|
#+---+---+------+----+------------+------------+
#|ALT|QWA|     2|null|    08:54:00|    23:25:00|
#|ALT|QWA|     2|null|    08:53:00|    23:24:00|
#|ALT|QWA|     6|null|    08:59:00|    23:30:00|
#|ALT|QWA|     6|null|    08:55:00|    23:26:00|
#+---+---+------+----+------------+------------+
```

I used [`pyspark.sql.functions.count()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.count) to count the number of items in each group. This returns a DataFrame containing all of the duplicates (the second output you showed).

If you wanted to get only one row per `("ID", "ID2", "Number")` combination, you could do using another Window to order the rows.

For example, below I add another column for the [`row_number`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number) and select only the rows where the duplicate count is greater than 1 and the row number is equal to 1. This guarantees one row per grouping.

```python
w2 = Window.partitionBy('ID', 'ID2', 'Number').orderBy('ID', 'ID2', 'Number')
df.select(
        '*',
        f.count('ID').over(w).alias('dupeCount'),
        f.row_number().over(w2).alias('rowNum')
    )\
    .where('(dupeCount > 1) AND (rowNum = 1)')\
    .drop('dupeCount', 'rowNum')\
    .show()
#+---+---+------+----+------------+------------+
#| ID|ID2|Number|Name|Opening_Hour|Closing_Hour|
#+---+---+------+----+------------+------------+
#|ALT|QWA|     2|null|    08:54:00|    23:25:00|
#|ALT|QWA|     6|null|    08:59:00|    23:30:00|
#+---+---+------+----+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is a way to do it without Window.

A DataFrame with the duplicates

```
df.exceptAll(df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'ID2', 'Number'])).show()
# +---+---+------+------------+------------+
# | ID|ID2|Number|Opening_Hour|Closing_Hour|
# +---+---+------+------------+------------+
# |ALT|QWA|     2|    08:53:00|    23:24:00|
# |ALT|QWA|     6|    08:55:00|    23:26:00|
# +---+---+------+------------+------------+
```

A DataFrame with all duplicates (using left_anti join)

```
df.join(df.groupBy('ID', 'ID2', 'Number')\
          .count().where('count = 1').drop('count'),
        on=['ID', 'ID2', 'Number'],
        how='left_anti').show()
# +---+---+------+------------+------------+
# | ID|ID2|Number|Opening_Hour|Closing_Hour|
# +---+---+------+------------+------------+
# |ALT|QWA|     2|    08:54:00|    23:25:00|
# |ALT|QWA|     2|    08:53:00|    23:24:00|
# |ALT|QWA|     6|    08:59:00|    23:30:00|
# |ALT|QWA|     6|    08:55:00|    23:26:00|
# +---+---+------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Please note that although using the `exceptAll()` method seems easier than the `window` to implement, it is highly inefficient and computationally intensive.

Answer (score 10):

To extend on pault's [really great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49561093/4629950): I often need to subset a dataframe to only entries that are repeated x times, and since I need to do this really often, I turned this into a function that I just import with lots of other helper functions in the beginning of my scripts:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window
def get_entries_with_frequency(df, cols, num):
  """
  This function will filter the dataframe df down to all the rows that
  have the same values in cols num times. Example: If num=3, col="cartype", 
  then the function will only return rows where a certain cartype occurs exactly 3 times
  in the dataset. If col "cartype" contains the following:
  ["Mazda", "Seat", "Seat", "VW", "Mercedes", "VW", "VW", "Mercedes", "Seat"],
  then the function will only return rows containing "VW" or "Seat" 
  since these occur exactly 3 times.

  df: Pyspark dataframe
  cols: Either string column name or list of strings for multiple columns.
  num: int - The exact number of times a value (or combination of values,
       if cols is a list) has to appear in df.
  """
  if type(cols)==str:
    cols = [cols]
  w = Window.partitionBy(cols)
  return df.select('*', f.count(cols[0]).over(w).alias('dupeCount'))\
           .where("dupeCount = {}".format(num))\
           .drop('dupeCount')
```

Comment: Just think how awesome this answer would be if `get_entries_with_frequency` had docstrings for the parameters, so somebody besides @Thomas could use it.

Comment: @pauljohn32 it has been a while since I wrote this, and I find it kind of hard to explain what exactly it does, but I did my best ;-)